# How does this encryption decryption work?

Tags: php, encryption, cakephp-1.2

I found this encryption decryption code in CakePHP's core classes after debugging why it's [not working on my server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087463/cakephp-securitycipher-is-not-working-specifically-on-server).

I'm just wondering the logic behind it. How exactly it manages to encrypt and decrypt? Why the for..loop with $j, and how XOR operator ^ help in this?

```
function cipher($text, $key) {
    if (!defined('CIPHER_SEED')) {
        //This is temporary will change later
        define('CIPHER_SEED', '76859309657453542496749683645');
    }
    srand(CIPHER_SEED);
    $out = '';

    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($text); $i++) {
        for ($j = 0; $j < ord(substr($key, $i % strlen($key), 1)); $j++) {
            $toss = rand(0, 255);
        }
        $mask = rand(0, 255);
        $out .= chr(ord(substr($text, $i, 1)) ^ $mask);
    }
    return $out;
}
```

Comment: A sample output can be found @ http://codepad.org/oXoewRmh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^` is the *bitwise XOR operator*.  So it's ciphering each character in turn by *bitwise* XORing it with a "random" character.  This operation is its own inverse, i.e. `(a ^ b) ^ b == a`.  So as long as you generate the same sequence of "random" mask characters during decryption as you do during encryption, you'll always get back what you started with.

The `$j` loop looks like it's using the `$key` to discard a certain proportion of the stream of values that `rand()` generates.  This looks like a cheap way of getting many different random streams out of the same RNG.  I'm not sure whether this is a very secure method, though.  Home-brewed attempts at encryption usually have extremely serious flaws, compared to established methods such as AES.

Comment: But in this function, since $mask is a random number, how could $out gives out encrypted/decrypted text?

Comment: @mmhan: `$mask` is not really random; it's being generated with `rand()`, which is always being initialised with the same seed.  So in fact, it's entirely deterministic.