# cakephp beforsave - cipher returns random value

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, encryption

I have model which uses `beforeSave(..)` to encrypt one field.
It works fine on my PC with WAMP server, but when I uploaded it to server, Security::cipher(..) method seems to return random value.

```
public function beforeSave() 
{
        if(isset($this->data[$this->alias]['somefield']))
            {
                $key = Configure::read('Security.salt');
                $cipher = Security::cipher($this->data[$this->alias]['somefield'],$key);    
                echo $cipher.'</br>'.$this->data[$this->alias]['somefield'];
                die;            
                $this->data[$this->alias]['somefield'] = $cipher;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

This code returns the same cipher and value pair on my PC but on server the value is the same but cipher generated from this value is random. I found this post [CakePHP Security::cipher() is not working specifically on server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087463/cakephp-securitycipher-is-not-working-specifically-on-server-solved) - I don't know if this is a problem but it says that cipher() uses srand which may be disabled - how I can fix this - I cant change anything in php config, I just have ftp access to server.

PHP on PC: 5.3.9
PHP on server: 5.2.17

Answer (score 0):

I found this: http://groups.google.com/group/cake-php/browse_thread/thread/7e6cda2e03a7c54?pli=1 it seems that its real bug, I just used this function this guy posted and it works ok.